# JS React /Declared but never used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started learn JS and have some problem in my feature. Goal of this feature - show 1 column of table and 1 column checkbox (for every row should be checkbox).

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table, Spin } from 'antd';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useFetch } from 'innroad.common.ui';
import * as apiService from 'services/ApiService';

const AccountType = (onSelectingItems) => {
  const [data, isLoading] = useFetch(apiService.getAccountType);

  return (
    <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
      <Table
        key="id"
        bordered="true"
        rowKey="id"
        dataSource={data}
        rowSelection={{ onChange: onSelectingItems }}
        pagination={false}
      >
        <Table.Column title="Account Type" dataIndex="accountType" />
      </Table>
    </Spin>
  );
};

AccountType.propTypes = {
  onSelectingItems: PropTypes.func,
};

AccountType.defaultProps = {
  onSelectingItems: () => { },
};

export default AccountType;
```

In this line I get error(**"'onSelectingItems' PropType is defined but prop is never used"**). But I used this line in my code and I should use it. What is my mistake?

```
onSelectingItems: PropTypes.func,
```

Comment: How are you using `<AccountType />` in the parent element's JSX?. Also, functional components receive a `props` parameter, you have destructure it: `const AccountType = ({ onSelectingItems }) => {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to destructure `onSelectingItems` from the props.

Try change your code here:

```
const AccountType = ({ onSelectingItems }) => {
  //code
};
```